# what are the options for the penultimate measure in the 3rd species counterpoint

Tags: counterpoint, species-counterpoint, fux

Mr. Fux says:

[image: fux fig. 53 & 54]

Then, Mr. Fux does:

[image: fux fig. 58]

In *Gradus ad Parnassum* (Mann's translation).

Is the last one a mistake? There's nothing written in the book that it's a mistake.

Comment: I got your kind note. Just know, the way to say "thank you" on Stack Exchange sites is by upvoting helpful posts, which you can do by clicking on the up-arrow next to that post.

Comment: It's important to note that the Fux examples figures 53 and 54 are in the Dorian mode, which has relatively simple cadence formulas, but figure 58 is in the Phrygian.  Because the penultimate CF note does not have a perfect fifth below it (B is a diminished fifth below) this cadence is very different.  I hope to post a more thorough answer soon.

Comment: @nuggethead are you still thinking of posting an answer?